# Covariance of $x_i$ and $\hat{\varepsilon}$ without exogeneity of $\varepsilon$

Tags: regression, covariance, univariate

What is the $Cov(x_i,\hat{\varepsilon})$ if $E(\varepsilon_i|x_i)\neq0$ in a univariate regression model?

Can the expression be simplified further beyond $\sum(\hat{\varepsilon}_i-\bar{\hat{\varepsilon}})(x_i-\bar{x}) = \sum\hat{\varepsilon}_i(x_i-\bar{x})$ ?

Thanks for all answer!

Comment: You seem to mix up two concepts of covariance: your first line refers to a theoretical property of an assumed underlying distribution whereas the attempted simplification refers to a sample statistic.  Which one of these concepts are you trying to ask about?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I missed the estimation hats.It's about the covariance of the estimated error terms with the regressor, hope that makes sense

Comment: The problem remains: the first covariance has almost no relationship with the summations.

Comment: @whuber Could you please elaborate or point me towards the right resources? I'm rather sure that the term is correct, so I don't know what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1):

So, by $\hat\epsilon$ I assume you mean the residuals.  The residuals are *always* uncorrelated with $x$ in a simple linear regression, because $\hat\beta$ is obtained by solving the equations
$$\sum (y-\beta_0-\beta_1 x)x=\sum \hat\epsilon x=0$$
$$\sum (y-\beta_0-\beta_1 x)=\sum \hat\epsilon =0$$

This is a fact about the estimators $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$, regardless of the model.

However, it is typically *not* the case that $E[ (y-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1) x]=0$ for new data from the same data-generating process.